# DOM traversal in Capybara testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

Quick summary: why can't capybara find the .admin-edit class?

So, I have built a site where there are published and unpublished articles and only the published articles are seen by guests while admins can see everything.  Login is handled through devise and a simple erb expression determines if an article is shown or 'published'.

I list articles on the index action of my articles controller and render a partial to display the articles.

```
<% if article.published %>
  <dl class="individual-article">
    <dt><%= article.title %> 
      <% if current_user.try(:admin) %>
        | <span class="admin-edit"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></span>
    <% end %><br> 
    <span class="article-tags">
        <%= raw article.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></span>
    </dt>
    <dd><%= truncate(article.body.html_safe, length: 200) %>
        <%= link_to 'more', article_path(article) %>
    </dd>
  </dl>
<% end %>
```

This works as expected but I cannot test for it correctly.  In particular, it returns false on expecting to find 'Edit' if the user is admin.

Here is my sign_in_spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "SignIns", type: :request do

describe "the sign in path" do
  let(:user)        { FactoryGirl.create(:user)      }
  let(:admin)       { FactoryGirl.create(:admin)     }
  let(:article)     { FactoryGirl.create(:article)   }
  let(:published)   { FactoryGirl.create(:published) }

  it "lets a valid user login and redirects to main page" do
    visit '/users/sign_in' 
    fill_in 'user_email',    :with => admin.email
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => admin.password 
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect(current_path).to eq '/'
    expect(page).to have_css('span.admin-edit')
  end
end
```

And here is my article factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title 'Title'
    body  'Content'

  factory :published do 
    published true 
  end
end
```

And here is my user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 

  factory :user do 
    email 'user@gmail.com'
    password 'password'

    factory :admin do 
      admin true 
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the error:

```
1) SignIns the sign in path lets a valid user login and redirects to main page
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('span.admin-edit')
   expected #has_css?("span.admin-edit") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/sign_ins_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have tried the following:

1. Eliminating the extra article if rspec had a problem with multiple classes
2. Changing have_css to have_selector and selecting the anchor tag
3. Drawing out the entire DOM root from html body ...
4. Checking if it was working outside of the spec by manually logging in as user with admin privs -> it does.
5. Tried deleting unpublished vs published article distinction but still fails.
6. Tried removing erb condition to check if article is published in view but still fails.
7. Tried making sure it wasn't loading via ajax (has backup in will_paginate) but fails.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

It now works if I avoid using the FactoryGirl importing:

```
@article = Article.create(title: 'Title', body: 'body', published: true)
```

Instead of

```
let(:published) { FactoryGirl.create(:published) }
```

No idea why.

Comment: Have you tried `save_and_open_page` after click_button Log in? Do you see the span?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show up.  Weird.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it might be related to having two users with the same email maybe it silently fails and because of that it doesn't redirect_to the main page and therefore can't find the span.

Comment: could be. I would recommend using the `faker` gem and use `Faker::Internet.email` to generate the email in your factory.

Comment: Yeah, I added the faker call to my factories which I use to seed the db and it still fails.

Comment: If you're loading that page, and the span isn't there, than one of the conditionals (`if <% if article.published %>` or `<% if current_user.try(:admin) %>`) is false. It isn't an issue of Capybara not finding the CSS; the CSS actually isn't there as you said. Which one of those conditionals is false (we can't see your controller)? Try putting a debugger like pry into the view or controller method and testing those two statements.

Comment: It errors out on `<% article.published? %>`  because it doesn't find even the .individual-article class.  I know that it is a testing problem because I've tested in my development environment.  I also checked changing the article factory to create only an admin article directly rather than through inheritance and it still errored out.  I think you're right and it's a problem with the conditions - not sure what though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec lazily assigns `let` variables, so at the time you display your page, neither the published nor unpublished articles exist. You need to use `let!` or `before` or otherwise ensure the objects get created prior to display of your page.

Comment: And it works!  Didn't know that it was lazily assigned. Thanks :)